# How do I attach new JVMs to spawned Python Processes?

Tags: java, python, jvm, multiprocessing, jaydebeapi

I'm working with a Python daemon running on Python 3.7 on a Linux RedHat VM.
The guts of the program are very CPU heavy so I've implemented Multiprocessing, threading was too slow. I'm required to make the program a daemon.

To overview, the daemon queries the DB and queues up all of the ids in a Queue. Then the process() function runs in each spawned process. The code works without error for 1-2 processes, but we want to run about 7. I've simplified the code below.

When I run the program with 7 processes I get the following error...

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "python_daemon_multiprocessv4.py", line 77, in process
>       cus_runid.execute("QUERY REMOVED”);   File "/PATH-REMOVED/jaydebeapi/**init**.py", line 498, in execute
>       self._prep = self._connection.jconn.prepareStatement(operation) jpype._jexception.java.lang.NoClassDefFoundErrorPyRaisable:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ibm/db2/jcc/am/dg

It's an error on a db connection, again that works flawlessly with 1-2 processes. I think is is because the processes are sharing the same JVM. This program is all Python, I only use the JVM to connect to the database.

```
import time
import os
import jaydebeapi, sys
import multiprocessing

def bigsql_database_connection():
    #creates a db connection with jaydebeapi

# Multiprocessing Variables
total_processes = 7
wait = 30
queue = multiprocessing.Queue()

# define daemon cursor
conn = bigsql_database_connection()
cus=conn.cursor()

def list_unprocessed_ids():
    #returns ids to process

def process(queue):
    conn = bigsql_database_connection()
    while True:
        try:
            cus_runid=conn.cursor()
            run_id_str = str(queue.get(True))
            #here some db work and heavy data processing is completed
            cus_runid.close()
        except Exception as e:
            cus_runid.close()

def daemon():
    run_pool = multiprocessing.Pool(total_processes, process, (queue,))
    while True:
        try:
            ids_to_process = list_unprocessed_ids()
            if len(ids_to_process) >= 1:
                for id in ids_to_process:
                    queue.put(str(id))
            time.sleep(wait)
        except Exception as e:
            #handle error
    return 0

daemon()
```

How can I give each process its own JVM so the processes don't fight over the db connection? (I'm pretty sure this is what is happening)

Comment: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ibm/db2/jcc/am/dg` sounds like a classpath / db driver configuration issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19128792/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-class-com-ibm-db2-jcc-db2driver-not-found-in-w

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted is a previous post, when using JPype with multiprocessing it is necessary to spawn rather than to fork.  Forked copies inherit a non functional JVM which leads to random issues.

[Memory leaks in Jpype with multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58695140/memory-leaks-in-jpype-with-multiprocessing)